# Show error (from fiddle) When not 'submit', but radio is selected (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hees1989/bcres4f2/) an 'error' message shows when clicking on the submit button.
Is there a way to show that message when clicking on a radio button in the second list. With a message like ('Select from the first list, first).

I'm currently just emptying the radio when the other's not selected (or the array to fill the radio is undefined), like below. But I want the user to actually see why he can't select from the second list yet.

```
if(typeof(dateTypeArray) == 'undefined'){
        /* In case of undefined dateTypeArray, show alert to choose customerType */
        dateTypeRadio.prop('checked', false);
        $(dateFieldset).hide();
        console.log('Selecteer group first.');
        return;
    } else {
        /* In case of defined dateType, show dateFieldset */
        $(dateFieldset).show();
        console.log('Group selected, show next..');
    }
```

If any other information is required, please ask. new to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So first you want user to select Radio button from first list and then he must be allowed to select from 2nd list??

Comment: Yes, but I've already fixed that. I just want an error message to show when he attempts to select from the second list without selecting from the first one. A same kind of error messages that shows when you push the submit button

Comment: That alert is browser default!! It's appearing because you have provided required to each input and that's html5 validation happening there. To provide same type of alert you need to write a html for the error and show it through jquery after validating!!

Comment: I can't show the html5 validation message when clicking on a radio button?

Comment: @Hees1989 - Just a general question. Why show/enable the second list of options if the user must select from the first list first? Why is the order important? Will the second list potentially change based on the selection in the first list? If not, then why force the user to select the first list first? If yes, you could either force a default selection on the first list which loads the second list choices and go from there or just hide/disable the second list until a selection is made in the first list.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl The second list will change based on the selection in the first. Setting a default will result in certain options not being available. Which might give the user an idea that they're not available at all, so that's not an option. Disabling is what i'm currently doing, that's why I wanted a message to show if someone tried to select from the second list first. I'll just keep it the way it was then. Thanks anyway!